# Removing Observer on button click

Tags: iphone, ios

I need to remove Observer
Here is my code add Observer

```
[self.imageCropper addObserver:self 
                   forKeyPath:@"crop" 
                   options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew 
                   context:nil];
```

My question is how can i remove this added observer on button click

Comment: – removeObserver:forKeyPath:context:   https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/removeObserver:forKeyPath:context:

Answer (score 0):

I can read about [NSKeyValueObserving Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

```
[self.imageCropper removeObserver:self 
                   forKeyPath:@"crop"];
```